# Returning date that corresponds with maximum value in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, yahoo-finance

I am working on a stock analysis tool in python. I have collected OHLC data from yahoo with the pandas datareader. My goal is to find the date which has the highest volume in my dataset. I used `tesla = web.DataReader("TSLA","yahoo", start, end)` 
`print(tesla["Volume"].max())` returns 7516791000.0 but when trying to use `print(tesla["Volume"].arg max())` it returns 538. My assumption is that this is means the maximum volume occurs on the 538th day in my dataset but how can I get this value in DateTime format so I can clearly identify the day with the highest volume?

Note: printing `tesla.info()` returns `<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 1258 entries, 2012-01-03 to 2016-12-30
Data columns (total 6 columns):
 #   Column     Non-Null Count  Dtype

---  ------     --------------  -----

 0   High       1258 non-null   float64
 1   Low        1258 non-null   float64
 2   Open       1258 non-null   float64
 3   Close      1258 non-null   float64
 4   Volume     1258 non-null   int64

 5   Adj Close  1258 non-null   float64
dtypes: float64(5), int64(1)`

I have been teaching myself python and am new to pandas and timeseries data and I can't find any answers in the docs/stackoverflow that solve my issue. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Do you have a Date Column in your dataframe?

Comment: tesla.index[tesla["Volume"].values.argmax()] should work for you.

Comment: @DerekO I tried tesla.index[tesla["Volume"].values.argmax()]  but it still returns 538, it seems to me that I might need to add a date column, but when I plot the data it gives me date ticks that correspond with the dates in the dataframe

Comment: Make the index your date column: tesla.index = dates in datetime format. Then tesla.index[tesla["Volume"].values.argmax()] should work.

Comment: @DerekO I got it to work. Thank you so much!